# "Uploading a new file will override these libraries" message when I upload a zip file to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am testing a script by uploading a zip file on-to AWS Lambda.

> This function contains external libraries. Uploading a new file will override these libraries.

I read the [Creating a Deployment Package (Node.js)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html) documentation, but I am not able to get a proper understanding.

What am I missing?

Comment: I get that in Java all the time and it still works just fine.

Comment: Well, it does not work in my case :/

Answer (score 3):

If you can edit your function code inline through the AWS Lambda console, it means that if you edit that single file (index.js or handler.js) will overwrite and replace the entire function with that one file. but if you upload the zip, there should be no problem

Answer (score 2):

If your script has node modules installed from npm, this just means that uploading will overwrite those node modules with whatever is in your new zip file.

It's only telling you whatever you had before will be overwritten.